# Implementing Search funtionality in Laravel/Lighthouse GraphQL API

Tags: php, laravel, graphql, laravel-lighthouse

I'm creating a GraphQL implementation of an existing API. I'm using Laravel 5.8 with Lighthouse 3.7.

I'm wondering how to implement a search functionality using this - something along the lines of...

## scheme.graphql

```
type Query {
    userSearch(name: String, email: String, phone: String, city_id: Int): [User] #Custom Resolver - app/GraphQL/Queries/UserSearch.php
}
type User {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    email: String
    phone: String
    credit: Int
    city_id: Int
    city: City @belongsTo
}
```

## UserSearch.php

```php
public function resolve($rootValue, array $args, GraphQLContext $context, ResolveInfo $resolveInfo)
{
    $q = app('db')->table('users');
    foreach($args as $key => $value) {
        $q->where($key, $value);
    }
    $users = $q->get();

    return $users;
}
```

This would work - but only for the fields that are returned by the query.

```
{
    userSearch(name:"Picard") {
        id          # This will work
        name        # This will work
        city {      # These wont.
            id      # These won't work
            name    # These won't work
        }
    }
}
```

I'll get this error when I try it...

`"debugMessage": "Argument 1 passed to Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Schema\\Directives\\RelationDirective::Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Schema\\Directives\\{closure}() must be an instance of Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model, instance of stdClass given, called in /mnt/x/Data/www/Projects/Phoenix/vendor/nuwave/lighthouse/src/Schema/Factories/FieldFactory.php on line 221"`

I know what is going wrong - the `$users` in the `resolve` function is returning a interatable object - and not a model - like `hasMany` or `belongsTo` returns. I'm wondering what is the right way to do this.

Comment: you probably need some `->join('cities')` (left?) in resolver

Comment: What you are trying to do should be possible to do without using a custom resolver. Just use the `eq` directive on your arguments instead https://lighthouse-php.com/3.7/api-reference/directives.html#eq

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do should be possible without using a custom resolver.

You should be able to do it with something in the likes of the following

```
type Query {
    userSearch(name: String @eq, email: String @eq, phone: String @eq, city_id: Int @eq): [User] @paginate
}
type User {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    email: String
    phone: String
    credit: Int
    city_id: Int
    city: City @belongsTo
}
```

Here we utilize the [paginate method](https://lighthouse-php.com/3.7/eloquent/getting-started.html#pagination) and extending it with some [constraints](https://lighthouse-php.com/3.7/eloquent/getting-started.html#adding-query-constraints).

Comment: This is helpful - but not exactly what I'm looking for. I want to add some filters in the resolver before returning the data(things like status = 1 and a few others).

Comment: You can do that by using the scope directive and then add the scope to your user model. Else if you could show a complete example of what you actually want, then I'll try and help with that.

Answer (score 1):

The best way that I've tried throughout my project is to add a public static `scopeSearch` function in the `User` model and perform search there, and then easily use the code below to do the search:

```
users(q: String @search): [User]
@paginate(model: "App\\Models\\User")
```

The `@search` will trigger the search function in your model.